# Check if json array is empty

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a little script which grabs some JSON content for a webshop menu. Sometimes a category doesn't have products in it so when the array is empty a "no products found" line must be showed. 
I tried this with jQuery.isEmptyObject() but now the text is only showed at categories WITH products in it. The menu itself works perfectly except for the thing above...

**So my question: How can I check if `json.products` or `product` is empty? If so how would you incorporate that and the end of the script?**

Probably an easy one for you.... I don't see it anymore ;)

What I have:

```
function widget(catId, catHref){   
  var url = catHref + 'page1.ajax?limit=4';
  $.getJSON(url, function (json){     
    var productsHtml = [];

      $.each(json.products, function(index, product){

        var productHtml = '' +
          ..... blablabla .....

        productsHtml.push(productHtml);
      });
      productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');


    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(json[productsHtml])) {
      $('#widget-products'+catId+' ul').html('No products');
    } else{
      $('#widget-products'+catId+' ul').html(productsHtml);
    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting an array to a string with this line:

```
productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');
```

So, just do this:

```
if ('' == productsHtml) {
    // blah blah
```

**Edit based on comments and edits to question:**

To check if `json.products` is empty, just check `json.products.length`:

```
if (!json.products.length) { // implies json.products is empty
```

You don't specify what `product` is and you never use it in the code above. If it's an array, check `product.length`. For a string, compare to `''`. If it's an object, then use `jQuery.isEmptyObject(product)`.

**Edit 2 based on comments:**

To check if the JSON object has a given property, you use `.hasOwnProperty()`, like this:

```
if(!json.hasOwnProperty('collection') || !json.collection.hasOwnProperty('products')) {
```

If there is no `collection` property, this short-circuits, and you know you don't have `collection.products`. If it has a `collection` property, it keeps going and checks for the `collection.products` property.

Comment: Well then is my question completely wrong! Can you have another look please? I've updated the question... thx!

Comment: I think again my question is wrong. Could you please take a look here -> jsfiddle.net/meules/AQzXL/1. A json file with products in it has 'collection.products' in it. A json file without products in it don't. I tried to explain it with some notes inside the code. If you could help I would be more then tahnkfull ;)

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are trying to do. Please see my second edit above; that should take care of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the length of the array like this.

```
if(productsHtml.length>0)
{
//do your stuff here...
}
```

for new question i have updated your code and added some comments to make you understand:-

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    var productsHtml = [];
    //here i am checking json or json.products is not undefined
    if (json && json.products) {
        $.each(json.products, function(index, product) {
            //checking if product is not undefined
            if (product) {

                //do your stuff
                var productHtml = '' +
                    .....blablabla.....

                productsHtml.push(productHtml);
            }
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');


        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(json[productsHtml])) {
            $('#widget-products' + catId + ' ul').html('No products');
        } else {
            $('#widget-products' + catId + ' ul').html(productsHtml);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Well then is my question completely wrong! Can you have another look please? I've updated the question... thx!

Comment: Thx for your update. The weird part is that 'no products' is shown when there are actually products. Any thoughts on that? I'm completly stuck on this one.

Comment: I think again my question is wrong. Could you please take a look here -> http://jsfiddle.net/meules/AQzXL/1/. A json file with products in it has 'collection.products' in it. A json file without products in it don't. I tried to explain it with some notes inside the code. If you could help I would be more then tahnkfull ;)